# Drupal commerce wishlist anonymous

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, commerce

I am starting up a Commerce webshop.

I would like to add the Commerce wishlist, but now the module is working only with registered users, for unregistered it does not work.

I set the role in the display block to anonymous, but even after changing this, I get the message that I have to log in to add something to the wishlist.

Can someone please advise me how to change it for use of anonymous users? I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: The wishlists are stored in the database against a user id, and since the anonymous user always has a uid of 0 you'd need to implement some sort of mechanism to track users based on (perhaps) a cookie. Of course, when a user clears their cookies, they'll lose the wishlist. The issue you're facing is at a higher level than the wishlist module (or even Drupal). Once you've found a way of identifying anonymous users correctly you'll be half way there. But I know that module and it would take a fair bit of work to re-jig it for those purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module instead of the [Commerce Wishlist](https://ww.drupal.org/project/commerce_wishlist) module, you can take advantage of its facility to also **display a flag to anonymous users**. For that, refer to what's written in the community documentation of the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module, i.e.:

> Flagging for anonymous users (even with page caching enabled) requires [Session API](https://www.drupal.org/project/session_api).

Something similar from the [README.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/flag/tree/README.txt#n63):

> Optional Installation
>
> 1) The ability for anonymous users to flag content is provided by the Session API module, available at http://drupal.org/project/session_api.

Be aware however that [Session API](https://www.drupal.org/project/session_api) isn't mentioned as a [dependency in the Flag module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/flag/tree/flag.info) either.

Comment: How to show a flag in custom product template in commerce 2 for D8?

Answer (score 1):

The maintainer of commerce_wishlist module has just released the [2.x-dev](https://www.drupal.org/node/2560545) now also supporting public wishlists. Furthermore social sharing of lists will be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [Commerce Wishlist](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_wishlist) you can use [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag), this do the same and more flexible. Also this work with anonymous users and have prepared Views for showing in blocks/pages.

Comment: How to show a flag in custom product template in commerce 2 for D8?

Comment: @Umair https://www.drupal.org/project/flag/issues/3157623#comment-13737555